# Change PHP registration form response to a dialog box

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a PHP form on my page as follows -

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "someone@somewhere.com";
    $email_subject = "subject";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

I want that when the submit button is clicked the success line comes as a dialog box on the page instead of a new page.
Unfortunately if this cannot be done then is there a way to stylize the text (success line) that comes after the submit button is clicked?
Thanks in advance and please help.

Comment: use ajax for this purpose.. Call this php page from the ajax and get the response. then you can show that response wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

1) create a hidden div on your form

2) On the main form create a link  to your ajax call. Include the record key info on the link you wish to transmit to the web server/data server that you wish to have returned.

3) In your attached .js file create the ajax call and response. In the ajax call query send the key for the lookup to your server side response php app.

4) On your server side create a php response app

5) Your server side app looks up the record information and transmits back via a simple "echo" command.

6) Your client side app will then receive the information. In the response section of your ajax call add the information retrieved to the hidden  and make the  visible.

7) add a "close" link on the popup to rehide the popUp.

I would recommend that you send the information via JSON. This is very easy on each side client and server you just add a "encode" and "decode" line for each.

Since this is a lot of sample code to display, if there are parts of this you need help with, just post those specific questions for the parts of code you need help with.